# SQL запрос не уходит в базу данных

Tags: php, mysql

Первый запрос  достаёт список из базы данных, далее к списку добавляется элемент, вторым запросом обновлённый список должен возвращаться в БД. Но последний запрос не исполняется, БД не обновляется. Все переменные для запроса генерируются, запрос верный. echo показыкает, что переменные содержат значения, всё верно. Но запрос иполняется, если вместо переменных сразу вписать значения. При каких ещё обстоятельствах запрос может ну исполняться?

```html
 $result = mysql_query("SELECT `list` FROM `nombers` WHERE id = '$nomber_1'");

 $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

 $list = ($row[0]).','.$nomber_2 ; 

 $result = mysql_query("UPDATE `nombers` SET `list` = '$list' WHERE `id` = '$nomber_1'");
```

Comment: Используйте mysql_error для вывода ошибок: echo mysql_error($result);

Comment: Вернул, что ожидал 1, но получил boolean. Просто echo возвращает "1".

Comment: Подробнее пожалуйста - кто что ожидал. Не стесняйтесь копировать тексты ошибок и вставлять сюда.

Comment: echo mysql_error вернул: Warning: mysql_error() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in... echo вернул "1".

Comment: Пробуйте просто `echo mysql_error()`. И пока вы не зашли слишком далеко - забудьте о расширении `mysql`, перейдя на `pdo`|`mysqli`.

Comment: Я уже писал, что использовал и просто echo mysql_error(), и что она вернула. Ответ этот такой же, какой будет, если запрос выполнится. А выполняется он если вставить значения переменных напрямую. И это самое интересное.

Answer (score 1):

В данном случает ячейка базы данных имела значение INT(принимает только цифровые значения). В запросе поступала строка. Перевод ячейки в текстовое значение (TEXT) позволил принять запрос.

Comment: Правильно стройте запрос, INT не оборачивается апострофами, и не надо будет менять тип ячеек

Comment: Пробовал и без апострофов - не принимает.

Comment: А размер поля INT какой?